# Custom opencounter causing layout glitch

Tags: marketing-cloud

When using the custom opencounter `< custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">` in some emails, it causes a large so-called img area at the bottom of the email. i see when the email has been opened the tracker converts to

`< img src="http://click.e-halldata.com/open.aspx?ffcb10-feb712787d630d7f-fe1f13777060017b751179-fe971573736d047e77-ff9a1574-fe2015797d65017a701c73-ffce15" width="1" height="1">` which seems to be causing the problem.

When I fixed the width and height to reflect proper width and height style, the space below the email went away, however exacttarget doesn't recognize the tracker when it is style as follows:

`< custom name="opencounter" type="tracking" style="width:1px; height:1px;">`.

Is there any way to ensure the space is not added to the bottom of some emails?

Comment: What CSS do you have in the head section of your HTML?  Anything that's referencing `img`?

Comment: Actually there is. It looks like the CSS for img (which I did not put in myself) is as follows: img{-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}. I noticed the same CSS in another HTML file that also has this issue. Could that be causing an issue?

Comment: Sure, because it'd be directly affecting all `img` tags -- tracking pixel included.

Comment: Removing that didn't seem to help. The spacing is still incredibly off, only when the email is viewed as a webpage.

Comment: And it looks like I found the root of the issue and it seems to be fixed! Thank you so much for pointing out the possible issue with img CSS!

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue on iphone and can't seem to correct it in the supplied template in Content Builder. I know it is something to do with the image tag in the css and seems to be an error in the template code. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically include the tracking code right before the `</body>` tag.

Generally speaking, it shouldn't cause rendering issues unless your CSS is being applied to `img` tags.

Comment: There was definitely something affecting the img tag, and I think I have it all squared away, thank you so much!